# VB.Net - Time Variable compare against Current Time

Tags: vb.net, time

Any help would be greatly appreciated here, I need to compare a time stamp from a variable to the current time and 'do something' if its older than x mins.

My Timestamp variable is a Directories last write time.

```
    Dim path As String = "directory"
    Dim trickle As DateTime = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(path)
    Dim time As String = trickle.ToString("HH:mm")
```

I then have the current time

```
    Dim CurrentTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim Testtime As String = CurrentTime.ToString("HH:mm")
```

I then need something like this, but I am struggling to find the way to write it.

```
If time < (CurrentTime - "00:15") then...
```

Thank you

Comment: Why you convert the DateTime to a string?

Comment: You would be better not converting to strings at all and compare the values directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any need of converting your `datetime` to `string`. You can do it like below without the conversion :

```
Dim path As String = "directory"
Dim trickle As DateTime = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(path)

Dim CurrentTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now

 If trickle < CurrentTime.AddMinutes(-15) Then
 '''''
 End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not convert the right type(`DateTime`) to a wrong type(`String`). Instead you can subtract `DateTimes` and you get a `TimeSpan`:

```
Dim lastWriteTime As DateTime = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(path)
Dim elapsedTime As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now - lastWriteTime

If elapsedTime > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15) Then

End If
```

Comment: Thank you, not used TimeSpan until now

Answer (score 0):

When you [substract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.subtract?view=netframework-4.7.2) two [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2) you get a [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2). With a TimeSpan, you have the difference in different ways, like [Minutes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalminutes?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Don't convert your dates to strings.